# How to Spectrum-inverse a sampled audio signal

Tags: algorithm, audio, signal-processing

I am looking for a simple (pseudo)code that spectrum-inverse a sampled audio signal.
Ideally C++

The code should support different sample rates (16/32/48KHz).

Comment: What is "spectrum-inverse"? Funny thing is, google revealed your question here as first hit.
You want the reciprocal of phase and amplitude for each frequency? Or you simply want just an IFFT? Or something completely different?

Comment: Sorry for my unprofessional vocabulary: I want the low frequencies to become the high-ones and vice versa (DC offset will become a sine with half the sampling frequency).

Comment: Now I am very curious to hear what this would sound like...

Comment: this sounds quite odd, I have to think about if this might work at all. "Inverting" just each sampling block might lead to inconsistencies at the boundaries, weird stuff might happen then?
While I doubt that your idea will result in anything meaningful/useful, why don't you just take the FT and reverse the array? Mhh..have to think about phase and stuff as well...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mixing the signal by `Fs/2` will swap high frequencies and low frequencies - think of rotating the spectrum around the unit circle by half a turn.  You can achieve this rotation by multiplying every other sample by -1.

Mixing by `Fs/2` is equivalent to mixing by `exp(j*pi*n)`.  If `x` is the input and `y` the output,

```
y[n] = x[n] * exp(j*pi*n) = x[n] * [cos(pi*n) + j*sin(pi*n)]
```

This simplifies easily because `sin(pi*n)` is 0, and `cos(pi*n)` is alternating 1,-1.

Comment: This trick comes up a lot in DSP. For instance, if you want to design a high pass filter, it's usually easier to design a low pass filter with the desired cutoff proportion, then rotate it around the unit circle to make it high pass.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get something that has the same type of temporal structure as the original, you need to

- Create a spectrogram (with some window size)
- Pick some upper and lower frequency bounds that you'll flip
- Flip the spectogram's intensities within those bounds
- Resynthesize a sound signal consistent with those frequencies

Since it's an audio signal, it doesn't much matter that the phases will be all messed up.  You can't generally hear them anyway.  Except for the flipping part, [ARSS](http://arss.sourceforge.net/) does the spectrogram creation and sound resynthesis.

Otherwise, you can just take a FFT, invert the amplitudes of the components, and take the inverse FFT.  But that will be essentially nonsensical, as it will completely scramble the temporal structure of the sound as well as the frequency structure.

Comment: Thank you, ARSS uses frequency filter bank, so all I can do is inverse the frequency bins. I Wonder if there is some mathematical manipulation that invert the frequencies 'smoothly' (without dividing it into bins).

Comment: You can use wavelets that aren't explicitly binned, but in your case that hardly matters.  Low frequency sounds change much more slowly than high-frequency ones, so the flip is going to alter the smoothness anyway.

Answer (score 0):

it does not make much sense to use a cosine. for a digital signal it is not neccessary to run a real ringmod here, at nyquist a consine is a square anyway.

so you would just multiply every other sample by *-1 and you are done.

no latency, no aliasing, no nothing.